# rootcint: error while loading shared libraries: libCint.so (XPS Package Installation from Bioconductor)

Tags: r, shared-libraries, root

I am trying to install the XPS package from Bioconductor. These are my steps:

```
#install libxpm library 
sudo apt-get install libxpm-dev 

~/downloads $ wget ftp://root.cern.ch/root/root_v5.34.19.source.tar.gz

~/downloads $ tar -zxvf root_v5.34.19.source.tar.gz

~/downloads $ cd root

~/downloads/root $ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local

~/downloads/root $ make

~/downloads/root $ sudo make install

#I am able to start root & quit root from any directory on my system
root (to start) 

.q (to quit)
```

However, when I try to install the XPS package in R:

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")

biocLite("xps", type="source")
```

I get the following error:

```
rootcint: error while loading shared libraries: libCint.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
make: *** [xpsDict.cxx] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘xps’
```

Just in case you want to know, I tried to search for the libCint.so library:

I cound find the libCint.so library in the lib/ folder where I actually downloaded ROOT
but the libCint.rootmap file was missing:

```
~/downloads/root/lib $ ls
...
libASImage.rootmap
libASImage.so
libCintex.rootmap
libCintex.so
libCint.so #no .rootmap file
libcomplexDict.rootmap
libcomplexDict.so
...
```

The libCint.so was missing in /usr/local/bin/rootcint

```
~ $ ldd /usr/local/bin/rootcint 
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff069ff000)
libCint.so => not found
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f4720636000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f472041f000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f472005f000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f471fd63000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f4720956000)

~ $ ldd /usr/local/bin/root
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff3a1ff000)
libXpm.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXpm.so.4 (0x00007f33e8966000)
libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f33e8631000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f33e8330000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f33e7f70000)
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f33e7d52000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f33e7b4d000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f33e7851000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f33e8b97000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f33e763b000)
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f33e7437000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f33e7231000)
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You only need to copy `~/downloads/root/lib/libCint.so` to `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`, and type "root -help".